# Android ) Using bitmap got by AsyncTask at Main UI

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, universal-image-loader, oncreate

I am making a puzzle application that can send my picture to my friend using server.

At this timing, server gives another player an image URL and app gets that image url and makes a bitmap object using that url...

1. First , I tried to make it using Universal ImageLoader

   > Bitmap bmp = imageLoader.loadImageSync(imageUri);

But I got **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error** that happens when Network is directly related to main UI.

my onCreate() :

```
Prefix pre = new Prefix();
bitmap = pre.gcmBitmap(getIntent().getStringExtra("URL"));
```

method pre.gcmBitmap(String url) :

```
    public Bitmap gcmBitmap(String url){
    //Bitmap bmp = imageLoader.loadImageSync(imageUri);
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    //imageLoader.loadImage;
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
    imageLoader.init(config);
    Bitmap bitmap = imageLoader.loadImageSync(url);
    //Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap();
    return bitmap;
}
```

So

2. For second, I tried to make it using AsyncTask,
   But at that time, at the method 'onCreate()', this method doesn't wait to get that bitmap asynchronously and return null for bitmap so made my puzzle empty...

   ```
       public void getBitmapFromUrl(String url){
   ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
   //imageLoader.loadImage;
   ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
   imageLoader.init(config);
   imageLoader.loadImage(url, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
       @Override
       public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
           // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
           bitmap = loadedImage;
           subOnCreate(); // do the work that should be done after getting bitmap object
       }
   });
   ```

So I want to know if I can solve this and how I can do that?
I'm expecting that I have to use 'onPostExecute' paradigm isn't it?

Please help me guys

my Manifest is below : I have 'INTERNET' permission!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.min.photozzle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.min.photozzle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name=".StoryGame_4x4" />
    <activity android:name=".StoryGame_5x5" />
    <activity android:name=".StoryGame_6x6" />
    <activity android:name=".StoryMode" />
    <activity android:name=".CustomMode" />
    <activity android:name=".Title" />
    <activity android:name=".Setting"/>
    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.min.photozzle" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".GCM.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".GCM.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".GCM.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.kakao.sdk.AppKey"
        android:value="@string/kakao_app_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Test"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: it's much easier to help you if you show us what you've got so far

Comment: @0X0nosugar  You mean my code?

Comment: yes, I mean some relevant piece of code

Comment: I updated First and am updating Second now ... please look at my update!

Comment: Are you sure you have the internet permission set in your AndroidManifest? You often find relevant info in the logs.

Comment: @Murphy Absolutely! I updated my question !

Comment: I am not sure how to understand this: "at the method 'onCreate()', this method doesn't wait to get that bitmap background and return null for bitmap "  -  could you add some code from the "onCreate()" to clarify?

Comment: @0X0nosugar Very grateful for your interefer in my question!

Comment: That means that before I get the bitmap object from image url asynchronously, the bitmap object is null so when trying to get the bitmap by image url, the code in onCreate() goes on with the bitmap object having null... so as a result, my bitmap is null and puzzle is null so shows nothing not the image server sends

Comment: ok, the "onCreate()" in your question belongs to your first approach. As you are saying, the value gets assigned too soon.   I think you should try to make the AsyncTask work, which means you get the bitmap in "doInBackground()" and pass it to "onPostExecute()" where you can use it for some ImageView

Comment: @0X0nosugar Thanks but isn't  your opinion the same as my second approach?

Comment: Well, yes. If you are calling that method from "doInBackground()". I was trying to explain how to use "onPostExecute()". If you are having problems with the implementation, I think it would be helpful to post the AsyncTask code.

Comment: And no, sorry, I was wrong, because the SimpleImageLoadingListener somehow does not fit into the AsyncTask concept. "doInBackground()" would be finished and at some moment the Listener would be called, but not inside the AsyncTask.

Comment: So in fact I think you can use "Bitmap bitmap = imageLoader.loadImageSync(url);" inside of "doInBackground()" and then pass the resulting bitmap to "onPostExecute()".

Comment: Really? May I request how to use AsyncTask and doInBackground easily? I have only experience using Universal Image Loader

Comment: I'm a little short on time right now, so I'd like to give you a [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html) and I'll look into your question again in about twelve hours. But maybe you won't need me any more by then ;-)

Comment: @0X0nosugar I'm doing now guys! I will update it again thank you for your sincerity!

Comment: @0X0nosugar I solved this problem, you're my savior thank you

Comment: It's good you were able to solve your problem. Would you like to write an answer to your own question about how you did it? This could be helpful for others facing the same issue in the future.